# SAS Date Format conversion

Tags: sas, date-formatting, date-conversion

I've recently started using SAS Enterprise guide and would like to convert the date "01MAR2014" to "MAR 2014". I've been googling but unfortunately no luck.

I've tried the following however it just returns an

```
SELECT input(put(StartDate,EURDFMYw.),9.) AS Order_DDD_YY
```

Does anyone know how to convert this?

Answer (score 0):

If your date is a SAS date, i.e. a numeric with date format applied then you can change the display by using the monyy5. format instead. Note that this will create a character variable that will no longer sort properly in reports/datasets, it will sort alphabetically instead of a date order.

```
put(startDate, monyy7.) as Order_DDD_YY
```

Otherwise you can apply the format instead of converting it.